# VPS nameserver setup?

Tags: installation, vps, nameservers

I bought a VPS a few days back and had a domain name registered. It gave me 2 nameservers.

I only have shell access (no Cpanel/WHM) and it's running CentOS 5. I can visit my site with `http://IP/` but not with `http://domain.com`. What changes do I need to make so that I can visit my site with `http://domain.com`. I'm really new at this and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this question more in place @ serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the guides that Slicehost provides you will be up and running in no time. In particular, you need to configure your server, install an appropriate web server, and configure it for your domain(s). Visit http://articles.slicehost.com/centos and follow the steps listed.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually did it following this tut: http://www.howtoforge.com/bind-installation-on-centos :)